# ICP scan matching failure

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, ROS people.

I am using ROS laser_scan_matcher but faced this ICP failure.

Please have a look the following video.

[YouTube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?list=UUUMq8_xIORNn1P_jkQ58vKQ&v=2-ru1r9uu9M&feature=player_detailpage)

Is there anyone who encountered this and any recommendations?

Cheers.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/35684/icp-scan-matching-failure./) by [enddl22](https://answers.ros.org/users/194/enddl22/) on ROS Answers with karma: 177 on 2012-06-04

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

(Warning: Shameless plug ahead)
Not sure about ICP, but you could also try [hector_mapping](http://www.ros.org/wiki/hector_mapping) and see if it works better. We normally get good results with the Hokuyo UTM-30LX scanner and similar scenarios like that shown in your video.

/edit: Updated results with hector_mapping. I found that increasing the scan queue size from 5 to 25 gets rid of all errors, resulting in nice map without inconsistencies. It's a interesting question why that is though, considering that it takes only 4-8% of CPU (probably idling waiting for transforms). Map looks like this:
[image: image description]

The results can be reproduced using [this launch file](http://code.google.com/p/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/source/browse/trunk/hector_slam/hector_slam_launch/launch/postproc_qut_logs.launch). Similar to [this tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/hector_slam/Tutorials/MappingUsingLoggedData), just start the launch file in one terminal:

```
roslaunch hector_slam_launch postproc_qut_logs.launch
```

and then play back your bagfile in another terminal:

```
rosbag play 2.5D_bag02.bag --clock
```

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2012-06-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [enddl22](https://answers.ros.org/users/194/enddl22/) on 2012-06-08**:
Thank you for reply. I tried to run with hector_mapping but it keeps complaining "lookupTransform base_footprint to laser timed out. Could not transform laser scan into base_frame." I might need time to run it with. If you could run it with the linked bag file, it would be great to see  results.

**Comment by [enddl22](https://answers.ros.org/users/194/enddl22/) on 2012-06-08**:
The bag file link is https://dl.dropbox.com/u/12446150/2.5D_bag02.bag
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've had problems using laser scan matcher in hallways as well, although the angular errors in your video are different than what weve seen.

Normally laser based ICP will fail by shortening the end wall as you approach, and lengthening it as you move away.

I think this is because, due to the nature of a 2D laser scanner, you will have points more densely packed closer to the robot than farther away down the wall, so ICP will tend to skew toward matching the closer points than the ones farther out.

If you have other odom sensors, try using something like [robot_pose_ekf](http://ros.org/wiki/robot_pose_ekf) and adjust the covariances of your laser odom.

---

Originally posted by [phil0stine](https://answers.ros.org/users/639/phil0stine/) with karma: 682 on 2012-06-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [enddl22](https://answers.ros.org/users/194/enddl22/) on 2012-06-08**:
Unfortunately, I only have the laser scanner and IMU, no odometry. Probably hector_slam would be good option if it works.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[image: image description]

More information could be found

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i2UIN-bkGe8&feature=player_detailpage

Cheers.

---

Originally posted by [enddl22](https://answers.ros.org/users/194/enddl22/) with karma: 177 on 2012-06-25

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rosfun](https://answers.ros.org/users/29313/rosfun/) on 2017-03-28**:
@enddl22 Hello! Which hector_slam packages did you use to achieve this 2.5D Map? I am working on it as well but I could only generate 2D map without pose estimation.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Well i can confirm that Hector Slam is really stable and robust. It is even that stable that you can use it on a Helicopter (Octocopter) like we did. Take a look [here](http://www.youtube.com/embed/-KzifavR6bA).

---

Originally posted by [tlinder](https://answers.ros.org/users/2680/tlinder/) with karma: 663 on 2012-06-25

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Bill5785](https://answers.ros.org/users/29209/bill5785/) on 2017-02-28**:
how did you build the 3d map by just hector_slam?